# Incoherent error: invalid object name

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I renamed a table from my database. So I also renamed my entity (from Favori to FavorisAffaire). Compiled successfully. But now, when I run my application, I get the error below:

**Invalid object name 'dbo.FavorisAffaires'**

I didn't have this FavorisAffaires in my solution!

I have FavorisAffaire (withount ending s). I suspect something is wrong in the background of my solution... I already try a clean followed by a rebuild but the problem is still there.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does this has to do with ASP.NET MVC 3? Please tag your question appropriately, in your case I suppose you are talking about Entity Framework?

Comment: @Darin: It is an ASP.NET MVC3 solution. But you are right, it seems to be more specific to an entity framework problem. I added the appropriate tag.

Comment: Have you checked the model?  Open up the EDMX in VS, click on the FavorisAffaire table and press Alt+F4 (open properties).  In the properties is a field for the entity set name.  For most words EF adds an "S" to the end of a table name to indicate the plural.  Remove the "S" if it doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: @Smudge202: oops I forgot to mention that I used Entity Framework Code First. Si I didn't have any EDMX files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how EF behaves by default. It uses pluralization of names. It can be turned off or you can force single entity to map to proper table but that all depends on the version of EF you are using.

Edit:

> oops I forgot to mention that I used
>   Entity Framework Code First.

Yes you forgot to mention very important part of your question.

There are several ways to do that.

Data annotation:

```
[Table("FavorisAffaire")]
public class FavorisAffaire
{ ... }
```

Or fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FavorisAffaire>()
            .ToTable("FavorisAffaire");
```

Or removing pluralization convention (this has global scope so it can break mappings of other existing tables)

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Once you remove convention you should ensure that name of `DbSet` is singular:

```
public DbSet<FavorisAffaire> FavorisAffaire { get; set; }
```

Or simply rename your table because tables should be plural.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ladislav Mrnka's answer, I assume that you haven't recreated your database, after you made these changes. So "Code First" generated a table-name for your new entity, that didn't exist before (to be precise, it was probably named "Favoris"). If you now connect to a database that already has the old schema, and you did not order EF to recreate the database, it will assume, that the table it is looking for (FavoriAffairs) is present (which it isn't).

If you already have data in your "Favoris" table, I suggest you rename it to "FavoriAffairs", otherwise let Code First recreate the database. This is done be setting a specific database-initializer, explained here: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/04/27/DatabaseInitializersEFCodeFirstDatabaseSetInitializer.aspx